# Xamarin Forms - Layout Cycle detected. Layout could not complete

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin forms page with a listview and a picker. On the changed event of the picker, I populate the listview. On Windows phone, intermittently, I get this exception:

`System.Windows.LayoutCycleException: Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a timeout issue due to the number of items set in the `ItemSource`.

I would explicitly set the height value of the `ViewCell` and the `Children` of that view cell so that `Windows Phone` doesn't try to calculate the height for every item

See this Xamarin Forum post for more info:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41813/layout-cycle-detected-layout-could-not-complete-after-resetting-listview-itemssource